# In the below line i get memory leak

Tags: ios

```
NSDate *today = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    NSCalendar *calender = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *onset = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [onset setMonth:monthsStart];
    NSDate *fromDate = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:onset toDate:today options:0];
    [onset setMonth:monthsEnd];
    NSDate *toDate = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:onset toDate:today options:0];
```

it says the following :-

1. Method returns an Objective-C object with a +1 retain count
2. Object leaked: object allocated and stored into `today` is not referenced later in this execution path and has a retain count of +1

Comment: Please go through this, https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011-SW1

Comment: Same issue as your last question. You `alloc` so you have to `release` it at the end or `autorelease` it at creation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The leak is because you are not releasing `today`. Please use `[today release]` and release the same. The same is the case with `calender` and `onset`. Immediately after the line `NSDate *toDate = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:onset toDate:today options:0];`, please release all these params.

```
NSDate *today = [[NSDate alloc] init];
NSCalendar *calender = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *onset = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[onset setMonth:monthsStart];
NSDate *fromDate = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:onset toDate:today options:0];
[onset setMonth:monthsEnd];
NSDate *toDate = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:onset toDate:today options:0];
//After you are done with the below variables, you can release it
[today release];
[calender release];
[onset release]; //you cannot use these variables after this line.
```

Also **please** go through this documentation, [Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011-SW1)

Comment: Nice pun: not releasing today. Lol.

Comment: Yup, noticed that now only. :)

Comment: @BhartiSyal, In that case, please use release/autorelease as we discussed in your last question. Do this for all alloc/retain statements in your code at appropriate places.

Comment: [onset release];
    onset = nil; should i even set it to nil after releasing it

Comment: You can do that. Just to make sure there are no garbage values in onset after releasing it. I prefer normally setting it to nil.

Comment: @BhartiSyal, yes. If you are not using it after that line, you can release it.

Comment: [NSDateComponents class]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x11283cd0
 -[CFCalendar class]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x13609050
 -[__NSDate class]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1360d620 and after adding the release lines i get the above message

Comment: @BhartiSyal, Where are you adding these release statements? You should add it after you are done with using it. Not before completing the usage. Check my answer now.

Comment: Are you releasing at some other place? Also are you sure that you are not using after releasing it?

Comment: Try setting those params as nil after releasing. `today = nil;` etc.. If that is not helping, have to see the full code which you are using.